# C# MVC Create Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using C# MVC. I have created a forms before where all of the data needed is on one form. Once the user fills, it then goes to the controller which inserts the data into a database table.

How would I handle a situation where the fields are on 3 different pages. On the 3 page, I like to submit. How does the data presist?

Also is a session variable Ok to use for data that is shared with many pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use different views, or use one view with a tabbed UI, and use three partial views as the content for each tab as an alternative.

You can use session, but then you have to ensure they can complete the content within the 20 minute time limit; as long as a postback occurs, then that limit is reset.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing a wizard style workflow you could just have a `ViewModel` for each page and as the user progresses through to each page store each `ViewModel` in a `Session` variable. Then upon complete you could grab all the Models out of `Session` then aggregate the values into your completed form state.

Another way would be, for each `POST` call service that persists the page data into a data store so as the user navigates through each page, the entity is populated and stored on your data base via some service.

Answer (score 0):

Could just have one partial view to spit out one single ViewModel that has properties for all 3 pages, and then use jQuery wizard plugins (or maybe you're writing your own) to simple manipulate the DOM to show/hide each page as the NEXT/PREVIOUS buttons are clicked. It will all still be part of one single FORM. And then hitting submit would post back to your controller method, say with a $.ajax() POST with serialized JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you shared a view model between all 3 of the pages in the Wizard, you could deploy HiddenFor fields on the pages to retain information that is not visible on that page of the Wizard.

This would persist data fields entered on other forms throughout your wizard and does not rely on the Session to store the information.